# Whats going on with this php switch while using isset within a case?

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
$a = true;
//b is unset;

switch(true) {
    case ($a): echo 'a';
    case (isset($b)): echo 'b';
    default: echo 'c';
}

//outputs 'abc'. expected output is 'bc'
```

Why is the output not as expected?

Update: Expected output 'bc' is a typo and should read 'ac'.

Update: I now see how this code produces different output than expected.  EVERY code section in a switch block after the first case that returns true will be executed, unless the switch is ended by a break.  After break point no other cases will be tested.  This is where my mistake was as I expected testing to resume per case with the absence of break statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code written by Isius is correct. It's just the nice trick to find out, which of following cases is true.

Your code doesn't work properly because you didn't put break statement to each case.

It should look like that:

```
$a = true;
//b is unset;

switch(true) 
{
    case ($a): 
            { 
            echo 'a'; 
            break;
             }

    case (isset($b)): 
            { 
            echo 'b'; 
            break; 
            }

    default:  echo 'c';
}
```

Output is 'a'. I don't know why you're expecting to get "bc" output.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you expect the output to be `bc`, when you have clearly set `$a` to `true`. You are comparing `true == true` which will obviously be a positive comparison.

What a `switch` statement does it take a value, then loosely compare it against the values specified by `case` statements. The input for both may be an expression. As soon as a comparison is positive, code is executed until a `break` is encountered or the end of the `switch` statement is reached.

So, to break down your code:

```
$a = true;

switch(true) {
    case ($a):  // $a == true, which is the case so we start to execute
      echo 'a'; 
    case (isset($b)): // isset($b) == true, which is not the case, but we still continue because of the lack of a break;
      echo 'b';
    default: echo 'c'; // again, we get here because there is no break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty unreadable and it has no sense.

This is not how switch statements work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here bu I think you have got slightly mixed up about how a switch statement works. A switch statement is essentially a more elegant way of having lots of IF statements. So if you have a variable $a and you want to perform some sort of logic depending on its value then you could do it using either IF statements or conditionals. For example:

```
//WITH IF STATEMENTS
if($a == 1) {
     echo "the value was 1";
}
else if($a == 2) {
     echo "the value was 2";
}
else { 
     echo "the value was not 1 or 2";
}

//WITH SWITCH STATEMENT
switch($a) {
   case 1:
      echo "the value was 1";
      break; //the break stops it just going onto the next case
   case 2: 
      echo "the value was 2";
      break;
   default: //this happens if none of the previous cases are true
      echo "the value was neither 1 or 2"
```

You can't switch on true though, true has no value to switch on - its just true.